# Dataflow Analysis: Available Expressions, why is OUT[B] initialized to universal set?

Tags: compilers, data-flow-analysis

In the dragon book, section 9.2.6, why is the $OUT[B]$ initialized to $U$ except for $OUT[ENTRY]$. Wouldn't using the $OUT[B] = \emptyset \quad \forall B$ be a more conservative solution? The book gives this example:

[image]

Let
$IN[B_2] = OUT[B_1] \cap OUT[B_2]$

$OUT[B_2] = G \cup (IN[B_2] - K)$

and $I^j, O^j$ be the $j$th approximations of $IN[B_2]$. Namely,

$I^{j+1} = OUT[B_1] \cap O^j$

$O^{j+1} = G \cup (I^{j+1} - K)$

The book argues that 1st approximation of $IN[B_2]$, $I^1$, is

$I^1 = OUT[B_1] \cap OUT[B_2] = OUT[B_1] \cap O^0 = OUT[B_1] \cap U = OUT[B_1]$

more "desirable". I don't see why we cannot initialize $OUT[B] = \emptyset \quad \forall B$ since based on the two dataflow equations above:

\begin{align}
I^1 &= OUT[B_1] \cap O^0 \\
&= OUT[B_1] \cap \emptyset \\
&= \emptyset
\end{align}

\begin{align}
O^1 &= G \cup (I^1 - K) \\
&=  G \cup (\emptyset - K)\\
&= G
\end{align}

\begin{align}
I^2 &= OUT[B_1] \cap O^1 \\
&= OUT[B_1] \cap G \\
\end{align}

This seems to be more intuitive to me, it says "the set of expressions available on entry into $B_2$ are those that are generated by $B_1$ and $B_2$" which seems on the right track. If any expression made available in $B_1$ is killed in $B_2$, $O^2$ will quickly fix this,

\begin{align}
O^2 &= G \cup (I^2 - K) \\
&=  G \cup ((OUT[B_1] \cap G) - K)
\end{align}

So my questions really are:

1. Does initializing $OUT[B] = \emptyset$ ever produce an incorrect analysis? In other words, when the Maximum Fixed Point algorithm terminates, is there a case where the set of available expressions is not a subset of the truly available expressions?
2. Assuming #1 does indeed produce a correct analysis, is the set of available expressions found using the $\emptyset$ initialization the same as those found using the $U$ initialization? If not, why is one larger than the other?